# IOS Facebook SDK can't get User info after log in

Tags: objective-c, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk

Alright, I am having a devil of a time with getting some basic user info from the Facebook IOS SDK (3.1.1). Having done FB development with other platforms I am pretty convinced my issue has to do with the FB app's set up than with my code. BTW, I am in iTunes and have set an iTunes ID for iPhone. I have also carefully checked and quadruple checked the bundle ID in the App set up against my bundle ID.

Right now I can authenticate with a test user and get all the detail, etc. It works great. When I log in as a real user like myself (and I am a developer on the project) I get an Auth token, but calls to get the user fail, and I'm not sure what I have done wrong (if it works for a test user it should work for everyone).

All I need to get from the user, BTW is their First name, Last name, FB User ID, and email address (optional, but requested).

Currently after authenticating using the I'm using the [games tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/ios-sdk-games/authenticate/). Once I am logged in I do the following (although I have done a bunch of other things with the same result):

```
 - (void)fbDidLogin
 {
    // removed the setup for the class level Facebook var that I am currently not using

    // get information about the currently logged in user

    NSString *fql = @"select uid, first_name, last_name, email  from user where uid = me()";
    NSDictionary *queryParam = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:fql, @"q", nil];

    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/fql"
                      parameters:queryParam
                      HTTPMethod: @"GET"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error) {
                        [self meRequestResult:result WithError:error];
                      }];
 }
```

The meRequestResult routine starts like this:

```
- (void)meRequestResult:(id)result WithError:(NSError *)error
{
 if ([result isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
 {
    NSDictionary *dictionary;
    if([result objectForKey:@"data"])
        dictionary = (NSDictionary *)[(NSArray *)[result objectForKey:@"data"] objectAtIndex:0];
    else
        dictionary = (NSDictionary *)result;

    [fbUserData release];
    fbUserData = [dictionary retain];

    NSString *facebookId = [dictionary objectForKey:@"id"];
    if(!facebookId)
        facebookId = [dictionary objectForKey:@"uid"];
 // and more follows that is not pertinent
```

When I turn on request logging in the FB IOS SDK. I see the same things and can not find any description anywhere what these mean.

Here's the last 10 or so lines from the log:

```
 2012-12-03 11:52:12.394 mTender[6572:1cd03] Reachability Flag Status: -R -----l- networkStatusForFlags
 2012-12-03 11:52:12.395 mTender[6572:1cd03] The internet is working via WIFI.
 2012-12-03 11:52:12.396 mTender[6572:1cd03] Reachability Flag Status: -R ------- networkStatusForFlags
 2012-12-03 11:52:12.396 mTender[6572:1cd03] A gateway to the host server is working via WIFI.
 2012-12-03 11:52:35.093 mTender[6572:1cd03] FBSDKLog: Request <#1111>:
      URL:  https://graph.facebook.com//fql?sdk=ios&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED&q=select%20uid%2C%20first_name%2C%20last_name%2C%20email%20%20from%20user%20where%20uid%20%3D%20me%28%29&migration_bundle=fbsdk%3A20121003&format=json
      Method:   GET
      UserAgent:    FBiOSSDK.3.1.1
      MIME: multipart/form-data; boundary=3i2ndDfv2rTHiSisAbouNdArYfORhtTPEefj3q2f

 2012-12-03 11:52:37.194 mTender[6572:1cd03] Error: HTTP status code: 500
 2012-12-03 11:52:37.196 mTender[6572:1cd03] FBSDKLog: Response <#1111> <Error>:
     The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)
```

Hopefully someone can figure this out. It's the last step of this project..

Comment: `Error: HTTP status code: 500` indicates a server error? How consistently does this happen?

Comment: Every time I use a regular user with the app.. I see that exact sequence of things

Comment: Is the app authorized in settings > Facebook?

Comment: Could you be hitting the rate limit set by Facebook for requests?

Comment: @peter-warbo, Not sure what you mean. Where do you mean? If you are asking if the app is authorized by the user, it is.

Comment: @david-thompson, unless the limit is less than 100 requests, I highly doubt it.

Comment: @james-webster, that sequence of events happens every time. I will need to go back and double check my settings. Maybe I am referencing the purchased, but not activated domain.

Comment: Have you tried the simpler approach...
if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
        [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
         ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
           NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user,
           NSError *error) {
             if (!error) { 
etc

Comment: also is this ios5 or 6 and if iOS6 how are you authenticating... through iOS or Facebook direct?

Comment: IOS 6, and requestForMe bombs as does any call for me (Open Graph, FQL, I have tried them all). I'm about to devolve to an older FB SDK.. This all worked at one point and then it didn't, so I created a new fb app (I'm not the app's original dev), and  updated to the latest FB SDK (wish I hadn't done that now)..

Comment: FWIW, this is now working for me. I reverted back a few months and miraculously things are working. Not sure what happened (and I suspect that Facebook fixed an issue.. this is typical).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'm going to close this out.

I reverted to an SDK back in November of 2011. It didn't seem to be working at first, and then it just started working. I suspect a bug on Facebook's end was causing this. I haven't updated to the latest again to try, but this is my only guess as to what happened.

If you've done any lengthy Facebook development you know that sometimes their bugs really make things difficult. That said, no idea if this is the actual answer since I really didn't make any coding changes from the original code.

I know that I purposefully left the bundle ID out of the FB App Setup..

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something very similar to you. I am using facebook for login so that I don't have to worry about storing passwords and what not.

I followed [this](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/) set of instructions.. The facebook site seems to be horrid the way its layed out with out of date stuff all over the place.

You can use native facebook or web based user authentication (the SDK will manage all that) so it will work on older versions of iOS and when not signed in to native facebook.

You will set a handler which will give you a "NSDictionary *user" with all the stuff that you need. No need to use the graph api on the iphone client.

Comment: I'll try this, but login seems to be fine.. btw, I've tried the normal request for "me" and that failed as well..

Comment: Are you getting the access token back ok?

Comment: So what is the problem.. do what I said and you will get everything. (First name, Last name, FB User ID, and email address) Just call [user objectForKey:@"email"]) when you have the user NSDictionary. Whats the problem.. its all been handed to you?

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try this method, BUT when I was following the original tutorial when I went to pull "me" (3 different methods, one is with FQL, OpenGraph call for "me", and there is a FBRequestConnection  mechanism for getting my data. None of which returned any info, but gave me an error that made no sense! Past experience says something is incorrect in my App setup on Facebook, but no amount of finagling has fixed it.

Comment: Have you set the facebook app id in your apps plist ?

Comment: I said I followed the instructions on the page. I actually did it multiple times to make sure I had everything covered. I get an auth token, but trying to use it essentially gives me an error that doesn't track to anything in any docs! (I'm not a Facebook Amateur, and have answered questions on FB in SO.. just that the new FB SDK for IOS is not working for me).

Comment: Uhhm.. after going through this it doesn't lead me to getting the user. It only gets me logged in which I could already do. Sorry, but this isn't really the answer to what I need. (I wanted to give you the bounty)

Comment: .plist file is all set up according to the article linked in the question.

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to see alternate way because the REST API has been deprecated. To make FQL queries you have to use the Graph API call.

```
 http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.query/
```

Comment: I won't deduct -1 you but honestly, what I am doing is the suggested path. The reference you point to says "To make FQL queries using the Graph API, check out the FQL documentation. You just issue an HTTP GET request to https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q= and provide your FQL statement as the value of the q parameter. You can use the Graph API Explorer to easily test FQL queries." This is EXACTLY what I am doing in the example code..